# Add class for children element depend on input value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children, fieldset

I have two `fieldsets`:

```
<fieldset class="checkable">
   <span class="as_cp_checkbox"></span>
   <input type="hidden" name="register_condition_01" id="register_condition_01" value="no">
   <label for="register_condition_01">data</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="checkable">
   <span class="as_cp_checkbox"></span>
   <input type="hidden" name="register_condition_02" id="register_condition_02" value="yes">
   <label for="register_condition_02">data</label>
</fieldset>
```

Now: i need to add `checked` class to `span.as_cp_checkbox` if in my input value is yes. I try with that but every time this class is appending for first `fieldset`.

```
var checkable_fieldset = $('fieldset.checkable'),
    checkable_fieldset_input = checkable_fieldset.find('input');
if (checkable_fieldset_input.val('yes')){
    checkable_fieldset_input.parent(checkable_fieldset).prev().children('span').addClass('checked');
}
```

How can i add class for this prev `span` which `input` have yes value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to add the class `checked` to all `'span.as_cp_checkbox'` preceding an input whose value is `"yes"` :

```
$('input').filter(function(){return $(this).val()=="yes";})
 .prev('span.as_cp_checkbox')
 .addClass('checked');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ifatak/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`checkable_fieldset_input.val('yes')` sets the value to yes.
you need to do `checkable_fieldset_input.val() == 'yes'`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the if statement should read

```
checkable_fieldset_input.val() == 'yes'
```

Right now you are **assigning** the value yes.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('fieldset.checkable input').each(function(_, input){
    if($(input).val() == 'yes')
    {
        $(input).siblings('span.as_cp_checkbox').addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but you probably should know that the first argument given to the callback isn't the element but the index.

Comment: A good practice in HTML/js is to test the code you propose as answer. It's very easy to confuse things like this one.